Unable to preserve date/ dateTime format along with integer format while reading excel file (.xlsb) using pyxlsb in python
I am trying to read the excel file (.xlsb format) using pyxlsb library in python and then convert that excel file to csv. But while reading the excel file the cells containing date/ datetime value are unable to preserve the format. Its getting converted into integer format.
Python code
import pyxlsb
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

def process_excel_xlsb(excelfile_path, outputCSV_path):

    workbook = pyxlsb.open_workbook(excelfile_path)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet('Sheet1')

    with open (outputCSV_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer csv.writer (csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')

        for rows in sheet.rows():
            row_data[]
            for cell in rows:            
                cell_value = cell.v
                #print(cell_value)
                if isinstance(cell.v, float)
                    decimal_vl = Decimal(str(cell.v))
                    row data.append(decimal_vl)
                else:
                    row_data.append(cell_value)
            writer.writerow(row_data)

    print('CSV created at {outputCSV path}')
    
excelfile path = 'my_file.xlsb'
outputCSV path = 'new_report CSV.csv'

process_excel_xlsb(excelfile path, outputCSV path)

Excel sample data
| S_no  |   Date    |  Float  |     Date_time     |
| ----- | --------  | ------- | ----------------- |
| 111   | 7/6/2018  | 111.999 | 7/31/88 1:00 AM   |
| 222   | 1/10/2020 | 222.999 | 9/22/86 1:00 AM   |

Current conversion
S_no ; Date  ; Float ;  Date_time    
111.0;43287.0;111.999;32355.041666666668
222.0;43475.0;222.999;31677.041666666668

I even referred to this solution from stackoverflow formatting-date-to-mm-dd-yyy-from-xlsb-file
But its also converting int/ decimal values to date.
I am expecting the created csv file to preserve all the integers, decimal, date format and date time format(YYYY-mm-dd).
Can some one please guide me on this.

You are going to need to convert the date-as-float format that Excel uses to a datetime format you want.
This answer covers part of what you are trying to do: Convert date from excel number format.  The following creates a list of which columns have 'date', 'timestamp', or 'time' in the column header.  Those values in those columns are then interpreted as floats and converted to a date format.
import pyxlsb
import datetime as dt
import csv
from decimal import Decimal


def float_to_datestr(d: float):
    day_0 = dt.datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal()
    days, time_frac = divmod(d, 1)
    d_out = dt.date.fromordinal(int(days) + day_0 - 2)
    hours, minutes_frac = divmod(time_frac * 24, 1)
    minutes = minutes_frac * 60
    h = int(hours)
    m = int(minutes)
    t_out = dt.time(h, m)
    dt_out = dt.datetime.combine(d_out, t_out)
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p' if (h and m) else '%Y-%m-%d'
    return dt_out.strftime(fmt)


def process_excel_xlsb(excelfile_path, outputCSV_path):
    date_col_names = ['date', 'timestamp', 'time']
    workbook = pyxlsb.open_workbook(excelfile_path)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet('Sheet1')

    with open(outputCSV_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, 
                            lineterminator='\n')

        for i, row in enumerate(sheet.rows()):
            # check for column labels that indicate a datetime
            if i == 0:
                date_cols = [
                    j for j, cell in enumerate(row) 
                    if any(dci in str(cell.v).lower() for dci in date_col_names)
                ]
                writer.writerow([cell.v for cell in row])
                continue

            row_data = []
            for j, cell in enumerate(row):
                if isinstance(cell.v, float):
                    decimal_vl = Decimal(str(cell.v))
                    if j in date_cols:
                        row_data.append(float_to_datestr(float(cell.v)))
                    else:
                        row_data.append(decimal_vl)
                else:
                    row_data.append(cell.v)
            writer.writerow(row_data)


Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. In your current code I can see that prior knowledge of the datatypes of the column seems necessary. But in my case I would be dealing with the processing of numerous excel files, where the prior knowledge of columns and their types won't be known. So, it there any way that the code works with any column names. I mean any way to determine that the float value the library is reading is of date or dateTime TimeStamp datatype and then only apply conversion?
